# Is it possible to create a BigQuery query for Looker Studio with a parameter populated from a table?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

As the question says, I have some tables in BigQuery and I want to create a query from some of them, using a parameter which is supposed to take predefined values in one table. The query is used in a Looker Studio report, and the parameter is supposed to be set by the report user.

To be more concrete, I am creating a report on orders using several tables. I want to allow the report user to filter by the categories ordered products are in. There are many categories, in the range of thousands, and they are prone to change in both their `id` and their `name` columns.

Since every product has several categories it is a part of, it's not an option to leave the category as a dimension of the table resulting from the query I am using for the report.

So is it possible to populate the parameter of the query with values from another table, like how a dropdown filter can get populated with values from a chosen column of a table?